# AC3 FlashPunk Console doesn't show anything

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-develop

I am making my project using flashpunk , I knew that it has a good console gui to give feed about states of the game , however when I tried making it appear with the FP.console.enable() method it shows its dark transparent GUI but no text appears .

I though it might be something wrong with my project so I downloaded some examples and they all failed .

Here is a pic from pink example :
[image]

As you see the console displays no text while it should give feed .

Answer (score -2):

Just try clicking ` (Under esc)
It will show you the console , the text , the statistics , everything but it will also pause the game (program).

Comment: Additional information about what this does, what problem you think it's solving, and how it solves it would be great.